# Git-cherry not ignoring whitespace as advertised

Tags: git

Given the following two versions of the `foobar.txt` file (excluding comments) ...

... on the upstream branch (version 1, commit 1):

```
foo
bar
```

... on the downstream branch (version 2, commit 2):

```
# (Blank line)
foo
# (Blank line)
bar
```

When I execute the `git cherry upstream downstream` command then it reports the second commit as **not** equivalent.

But after reading the manpage of the `git-cherry` command, GIT-CHERRY(1) ...

> The equivalence test is based on the diff, after removing whitespace and line numbers. git-cherry therefore detects when commits have been "copied" by means of git-cherry-pick(1), git-am(1) or git-rebase(1).

I would assume that the two commits consisting of the first and second version of the `foobar.txt` file are deemed as equivalent. Why is that so?

Comment: The traditional meaning of whitespace-ignoring diff is that it ignores whitespace changes within a line, but not any added or deleted lines. I don't know whether that's the intention here, but it seems plausible.

Comment: But how do you then interpret the phrase "and line numbers"? From my understanding blank lines do change line numbers.

Comment: I would guess the "line numbers" are the starting lines of each hunk (rather than the lengths).